# Unity3d texture size different than original png image

Tags: unity, android, textures, materials

While selecting a png image as a texture for a material in Unity, it shows different size (bigger) than the actual file size, why is this so?
how can I reduce its effective size to make it perform better without loosing much detail.

Size in windows explorer (825 kb)

[image]

and this is same image in Unity texture select window (1.3 MB)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: texture import settings]

Take a look at your import settings for the texture. Setting a different value in the Max Size field will have an effect on the disk space it will take up in a build.

Comment: Yea, I know that, but my question is why does Unity3d increasing the image size, even the original file size itself is smaller.